# How to Set Scrapy Auto_Throttle Settings

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

My use case is this: I have `10 spiders` and the `AUTO_THROTTLE_ENABLED` setting is set to `True`, globally. The problem is that for one of the `spiders` the runtime WITHOUT `auto-throttling` is 4 days, but the runtime WITH auto-throttling is 40 days...

I would like to find a balance and make the spider run in 15 days (3x the original amount). I've been reading through the `scrapy` documentation this morning but the whole thing has confused me quite a bit. Can anyone tell me how to keep `auto-throttle` enabled globally, and just turn down the amount to which it throttles?

Answer (score 3):

If someone in 2020+ still needs an answer. You can override any global settings per spider:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider

Answer (score 2):

from [AutoThrottle extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html) here
just add:

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1.5
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 2
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 6
....
```

anything you want in settings.py

Answer (score 1):

set `DOWNLOAD_DELAY = some_number` where `some_number` is the delay (in seconds) you want for every request and `RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY = False` so it can be static.

Answer (score 1):

Auto_throttle is specifically designed so that you don't manually adjust `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`. Setting the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` to some number will set an lower bound, meaning your `AUTO_THROTTLE` will not go faster than the number set in `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`. Since this is not what you want, your best bet would be to set `AUTO_THROTTLE` to all spiders except for the one you want to go faster, and manually set `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` for just that one spider without `AUTO_THROTTLE` to achieve whatever efficiency you desire.